# IE8 moves popup browser window to background

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

I need to open the popup dialog and then set focus on an element of a parent window. But as soon as the focus is set (after 5 seconds), the popup dialog moves to background (this behavior is reproducible for IE8 only).

There is the code to demonstrate this behavior:

Parent Page:

```
<h:head>
    <h:outputScript name="jquery.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var showPopup = function () {
            window.open("http://localhost:8880/pages/reader.xhtml", "Popup");
        };

        var setupFocus = function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#mainFrm\\:nameInp').focus();
            }, 5000);
        };
    </script>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="mainFrm">
        <h:inputText id="nameInp"/>
        <h:commandButton type="button" onclick="showPopup(); setupFocus()" value="Show Popup"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Popup Dialog Page (it is empty):

```
<h:head>

</h:head>
<h:body>

</h:body>
```

Is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: Looks like your code does what you describe so what are you expecting it to do?

Comment: _To reproduce the problem_
Open a parent page; press 'Show Popup' button; wait more than 5 seconds.

_Expected behavior_
The popup dialog should stay on a foreground.

_Current behavior_
The popup dialog moves to background: the parent page is on foreground after the focus is set.

Comment: Well... that makes sense doesn't it? Because you set focus to the parent page, this page will move to the foreground and the popup to the background. If you want the popup to stay on the foreground, you should set focus to the popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior seems to be "as designed". After all, you are setting focus to an element outside of the pop up window, so it makes sense that the pop up window gets moved to the background.

Comment: I have noticed that if I replace the popup URL with, for example, http://www.google.com, the code behaves as expected: the popup stays on foreground even after 5 seconds delay. So if the problem is present or not depends on the popup content at least.

Comment: @yaskovdev: I wonder if the pop up window setting focus to something inside of itself on-load has something to do with this.